# javascript image upload in php

Tags: javascript, php

how to upload an image by javascript without submitting form in php?
my requirement is to upload an image from my page without submitting the form.

index.html

```
<script>
function uploadme() {
    $('#redactor_content').redactor({
        imageUpload: 'process.php'
    });
}
</script>

<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="button" onclick="uploadme()" value="upload" /> 
</form>
</body>

<br/>
```

process.php

```
$dir = 'upload/';
$_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
 || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
 || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
 || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
 || $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg') {
    $file = $dir.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);
}
```

Comment: You need a hell a of a lot more code than that to upload a file. Or find a plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try AJAX jQuery uploader.

[Jquery File Upload 1](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

[Jquery File Upload 2](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/09/multiple-ajax-image-upload-jquery.html)